# Error using flume while fetching twitter data to hdfs

Tags: hdfs, flume

While fetching the twitter data to HDFS using FLUME , I m getting this error again and again as far as i have changed the versions of the twitter4j.jar files ,please tell me why this error is coming.Can anyone suggest me what will be the next step for fetching the data in HDFS ;

> (conf-file-poller-0) [DEBUG
>   -org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.getClass(DefaultSourceFactory.java:60)]
>   Source type org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource is a custom
>   type 2017-11-01 15:29:12,648 (conf-file-poller-0) **[ERROR -
>   org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:150)]
>   Unhandled error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StatusListener;)V**    at
>   org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.configure(TwitterSource.java:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:326)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:141)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding Twitter4j Stream » 3.0.3 & Twitter4j Core » 3.0.3 .